# OpenWebStart + IcedTea-Web: j2se element

Tags: java, java-web-start, icedtea-web, openwebstart

With [OpenWebStart](https://openwebstart.com/) (Java SE 11), what URL should we use in the j2se element?

```
<j2se href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" version="11+"/>
```

This link seems to be dead.

The "autodl" in the path seems to indicate that there should be some kind of auto download.

Which URL(s) does OpenWebStart support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using OpenWebStart you do not need to configure such href. OpenWebStart will automatically download a JVM from a dedicated server and manages it internally to start the application.